# Add references Visual Studio 2010 (NuGet)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to use some references in Visual Studio, I have installed **NuGet** to use some libraries.

**Is there a way to use only part of the package installed with NuGet?** For example, if I am using TeklaOpenApi and the following .dll files are installed with this package:

- TeklaModel
- TeklaDialog
- TeklaDrawing

Use for example just TeklaModel, could I do this using NuGet?

Comment: Not with NuGet, AFAIK. You'd have to reference the dll manually. That being said, I never used TeklaOpenApi so I couldn't tell you if you should do that but since the package installed two additional files are you sure they're not dependencies for the main file?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use only part of the package installed with NuGet?

I am **afraid** that you cannot get what you want. It is designed by nuget package. Usually, when the nuget package contains other dlls which means they are probably depended on a master DLL, or used at runtime.

All of them play an important role in this nuget, so we cannot easily remove them.

**Although** we can use Assembly Reference format(Right-click on `References`-->`Add Reference`--> choose one Dll) to reference the specific dll, but there is a risk that if the DLL depends on other corresponding DLL, an error will be reported. So we don't recommend it.

The best way is to  install the whole nuget package with all the related dlls.

Hope it could help you.